# iOS NavigationController - Best Practice

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationcontroller

I'm new to iOS programming and was wondering, should you only use a navigation controller if your entire app will be embedded in it? I've embedded view controllers for login/signup screens and was wondering for the actual game play controllers, is it bad practice to navigate to an entirely new view controller? Or should I push to another screen in the navigation controller to start a new game etc...

Any advice will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @Sausagedioxide I embedded the login/sign up screens in a navigation controller so the user can hit the 'back' button, right? but once sign up is completed, they shouldn't be able to go back to those screens. So I'm asking should I then segue to a view controller that is NOT embedded in the previous nav controller? Or is that bad practice since it's breaking from the nav controller...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best practice to use UINavigationController is to use them whenever you want to able the user to go back, and/or if you want to add bar buttons to it (For example to add new items, to perform a search, to open settings, and so on).

You can even work with several navigation controllers in the same application according to your needs. You want to understand first the flow that your application will have.